# Custom post type title of each author in his own post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, author

I have a seriously problem :( maybe someone can help me

The users registered in my wordpress page have one post only, and i created custom_post_type named "ofertas". The users can create one oferta only. With this code show the oferta title on index.php, the problem is show the oferta title in ALL POSTS. I want only show his own oferta title (if they have).

```
<?php 
// First loop
while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
author_id = get_query_var('author');
    $ofertas = array();

// Second Loop
$i = 0;
$args = array(
    'author' => $author_id,
    'post_type' => 'ofertas'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); // check if it has offers, if it has, loop over the offers
        $ofertas[$i]['title'] = get_the_title(); // or anything you need
        $i++;
    endwhile; // close the loop
else: // if it has no post
    continue; // we don't display the post
endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
<div class="post">
<?php
the_title(); // or anything you need

foreach ($ofertas as $oferta):
    echo $oferta['title']; // we display the title of the offer
endforeach;
?>
</div>
<?php  endwhile; ?>
```

I created the custom_post_type with this code

```
add_action('init', 'crear_tipo_ofertas', 0);

function crear_tipo_ofertas() {
$labels = array(
  'name'               => _x( 'Ofertas', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
  'singular_name'      => _x( 'Oferta', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
  'menu_name'          => __( 'Ofertas', 'text_domain' ),
  'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Oferta Padre', 'text_domain' ),
  'all_items'          => __( 'Ofertas', 'text_domain' ),
  'view_item'          => __( 'Ver Oferta', 'text_domain' ),
  'add_new_item'       => __( 'Añadir Oferta Nueva', 'text_domain' ),
  'add_new'            => __( 'Añadir', 'text_domain' ),
  'edit_item'          => __( 'Editar Oferta', 'text_domain' ),
  'update_item'        => __( 'Actualizar', 'text_domain' ),
  'search_items'       => __( 'Buscar Ofertas', 'text_domain' ),
  'not_found'          => __( 'Ofertas no encontradas', 'text_domain' ),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Ofertas no encontradas en Papelera', 'text_domain' ),
  );

$rewrite = array(
  'slug'                => 'oferta',
  'with_front'          => true,
  'pages'               => true,
  'feeds'               => true,
  );

$args = array(
  'label'               => __( 'oferta', 'text_domain' ),
  'description'         => __( 'Ofertas Spas y Balnearios', 'text_domain' ),
  'labels'              => $labels,
  'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
  'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
  'hierarchical'        => false,
  'public'              => true,
  'show_ui'             => true,
  'show_in_menu'        => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
  'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
  'menu_position'       => 5,
  'menu_icon'           => site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/images/logo.png',
  'can_export'          => true,
  'has_archive'         => 'ofertas',
  'exclude_from_search' => false,
  'query_var'           => 'ofertas',
  'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
  'capability_type'     => 'post',
  );

register_post_type('ofertas', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'crear_tipo_ofertas', 0);
```

Comment: You only want to show the author's post? One per user?

Comment: i want show oferta per user/post @Strap1

Comment: and yes, the users only have permission for one post and one custom_post @Strap1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to show a post by a certain user with a *custom post type*

Here is the code I would use, it might use a little more customizing, but it should give you the effect you want.

```
<?php
function display_oftera_post () {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo(); // Logged in User

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // If User is logged in, display the post

        $args = array( // Post Arguments
            'post_type' => 'oftera', // Post Type
            'author'    => $current_user->ID
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args);
                while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                                     <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                     <p> <?php the_content(); ?> </p>
        <?php endwhile;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: this code paste inside index.php?

Comment: the user is not logging. I need author of post, not user login

Comment: This would be in the *function.php* and call the function up on *index.php* using `<?php display_oftera_post(); ?>` but it seems I don't understand what your trying to accomplish.